# Delete rows from Table1 when Table1.COL = Table2.Col

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, subquery, sql-delete

I have 2 tables(comparison & comparison_2). Comparison table has many rows while comparison_2 is actually a small subset of comparison. Both of these tables have two similar columns named Barcodes, i want to delete from comparison all those rows which have matching barcodes with comparison_2.
I hope i am very clear with my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `exists`:

```
delete from comparison
where exists (select 1 from comparison_2 c2 where c2.barcode = comparison.barcode)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
SELECT barcodes FROM comparison 
EXCEPT 
SELECT barcodes FROM comparison_2
```

returns all the `barcodes` of `comparison` that do not exist in `comparison_2`.

Use it in your `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE FROM comparison
WHERE barcodes NOT IN (
  SELECT barcodes FROM comparison 
  EXCEPT 
  SELECT barcodes FROM comparison_2
)
```

Or even simpler:

```
DELETE FROM comparison
WHERE barcodes IN (SELECT barcodes FROM comparison_2)
```